# How to add php code inside pages created by admin of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When we create a new page from admin. We are allow to add markup language like html and content to the pages. But why i am not able to add php scripts. like 
`<?php function... ?>`

Comment: This is not a good idea.... use the WP shortcode functionality instead of writing php into the page content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, it also isn't very safe. Content and software should be separated.
You might want too checkout [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and add a few of those to do things you want.

Comment: I want to add site url to anchor whenever i click link. for eg. Inside admin page i added an anchor <a href="[site_url]/temrms">Terms and condition </a> the shortcode doesnt work in anchor. how to overcome this.

Comment: There is a link button in the editor to do this. Also for shortcodes to work you need to create/register them

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called Exec-PHP http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/ which will allow you to write your own php on a post or page.

As @janw says it isn't very safe so use with caution.

Comment: thanks for the plugin. Can you tell me why shortcode isnt working in hyperlinks like  <a href="[site_url]/terms">terms</a> i created this shortcode form function.php

Comment: And also bear in mind that if effectively makes it unusable for non-dev admins, as you have to disable Visual view. I've seen it used loads, the site ends up a dog's dinner.